# How to update a SQL-Server 2008 table with records from the same table with different ID values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Member table with IDNumber, Birthdate, Option and ID columns. The ID is a guid and is the PK.

Now, some Members are on Option 1 and have all the columns filled with data (IDNumber, Birthdate).
Some Members are on other Options. 
In this example, there are members on Option 3, who have the same IDNumbers as the Members on Option 1 (they are in fact the same Members, with multiple options).
However, the Birthdate column for these members is empty.
I am trying to update my table to match the Birthdate values from Members on Option 1 to reflect on Option 3.

In essence,

```
Option  |IDNumber   |Birthdate
-----------------------------------
1       |123        |19900101
1       |234        |19800101
3       |123        |
3       |234        |
```

How would I go about updating to reflect the missing birthdates for Option 3?
I have attempted so far:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (
  --birthdate int,
  idnumber VARCHAR(13)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (idnumber)
SELECT IDNumber
FROM Member
WHERE
OPTION = 1
    AND IDNumber IN (SELECT IDNumber FROM Member WHERE OPTION = 3)

UPDATE Member
SET BirthDate = m2.BirthDate
FROM Member m2
INNER JOIN @temp m ON m.idnumber = m2.IDNumber
WHERE
OPTION = 3
```

Which says it affected the records, but not the members under Option 3.

I also tried to do:

```
update member set BirthDate = (select BirthDate from Member where
Option=1 and IDNumber in(select IDNumber from Member
where Option=3))
where Option=3
```

Which returns and error of

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Please could you assist in pointing out where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Seems like the wrong approach. Don't store birthday several times. You need a separate table!

Comment: @Nicholas so you want Id `123` for `Option3` to have to have the Birthdate to `19900101`. Similarily the Birthdate for Id `234` and `Option3` should be set to `19800101`?

Comment: Members should only appear once in your Members table, and you should have a related Options table that links on Member Id. Your design is incorrect and it's the reason you are having this issue.

Comment: @tanner i Have an ID field that is a GUID, so these members may be "unique". This is the only instance i have where there are more than one

Comment: @Kane yes basically that is the goal

Comment: @NicholasAysenyour structure is still wrong if this can happen

Comment: @Tanner I know the design is wrong. as i said, this is the only instance. i would create a separate table if i could, but this isn't an option at this time. i know best practice calls for separate tables, with FK's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    UPDATE member SET Birthdate = A.Birthdate
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT tOption ,IDNumber ,Birthdate
        FROM member 
        WHERE Birthdate > 0
    ) A WHERE A.IDNumber = member.IDNumber AND member.Birthdate = 0
```

Comment: thanks. yours worked best for me in this instance. will keep the others for future use. thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one. Works fine If what I understood from your question is correct.

```
    ;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT M3.ID ,M1.BIRTHDATE   FROM MEMBER M1
    INNER JOIN MEMBER M3 ON M1.IDNUMBER = M3.IDNUMBER AND M1.OPTION=1 AND M3.OPTION=3
    )

    UPDATE MEMBER SET MEMBER.BIRTHDATE = CTE.BIRTHDATE WHERE MEMBER.ID =CTE.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cursor. That would look something like this

```
    DECLARE @idNumber int, @birthdate datetime

    DECLARE oprtion1_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT IdNumber,Birthdate
    FROM Members WHERE Option = 1

    OPEN oprtion1_cursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM oprtion1_cursor
    INTO @idNumber , @birthdate

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
    UPDATE Members SET Birthdate = @birthdate WHERE IDNumber = @idNumber AND Option = 3

    FETCH NEXT FROM oprtion1_cursor   
    INTO @idNumber , @birthdate 

    END

    CLOSE oprtion1_cursor;
    DEALLOCATE oprtion1_cursor;
```

Comment: You could do this in set based instead of looping.